# Remoção de Event Handlers

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Em uma aplicação `Xamarin.Android`, é importante remover os `Event Handlers` ao sair da tela para evitar consumo de memória? Seria uma boa prática?

Por exemplo, no `OnCreate()` de uma das telas do meu app, tenho a seguinte declaração:

```
_btnStartExam.Click += ShowStartExamConfirmation;
```

Ao sair da tela, por exemplo no `OnDestroy()`, é recomendado que seja feito o seguinte?

```
_btnStartExam.Click -= ShowStartExamConfirmation;
```

Li em alguns posts do SO americano que mesmo que o `Garbage Collector` faça esse tipo de trabalho, é recomendado para evitar referências cíclicas e consumo de memória.

Contudo, mesmo assim gostaria de mais informações sobre isso e se é bom para o ciclo de vida do aplicativo fazer uso desse tipo de técnica.

**Vale ressaltar que o aplicativo fica aberto o dia inteiro no dispositivo e o usuário não tem opção de sair para outras aplicações.**

Comment: você pode usar o OnDestroy para isso , mas tudo feito no OnCreate vai ser desfeito no OnDestroy por conta própria quando a tela for fechada .